# how do i access json object nested within each other using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

how can i access baggage in this json

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Results": [
            [{

                "Segments": [
                    [{
                            "Baggage": "2 PC(s)"
                        }

                   ]
                ]

            }]
        ]
    }
}
```

if i do Results.Segmenets.Baggage i dont get anything in  my console
please show me how to get baggage from this nested json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your json you have double array inside `Results` and `Segments`:

```js
Response.Results[0][0].Segments[0][0].Baggage
```